# Should i create separate activity to check user is logged in?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to check user is logged in or not. If yes then show home screen, else show login Screen.

Now I thought of two ways for doing it.

1) make login activity as start up activity, check onCreate() user is logged in if yes then show  main screen.

2) create separate activity for checking user is logged in or not.

if logged in then show main screen, otherwise show login screen.

But i am confused which way i should do it?
Is there any standard way to do this?
Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an extra Activity to make the switch, and basically do nothing else then that switch and boot up the correct next Activity, is the easiest but it will cause an extra transition effect which isn't the best option visually.

This is not very noticeable though for most users, so if you're under time pressure you could do this, and update it later when time is more flexible. It's not a terrible way to do it.

A better option, would be to have 1 main Activity, which checks the situation and will load the correct Fragment. If you're familiar with Fragments, this will not even take a lot longer then the extra-Activity option.

Comment: I m not much familiar with fragments. What's main advantage of fragments in this case?

Comment: A fragment is a re-usable 'block' which you can use within Activities. In this way, 1 Activity can show multiple Fragments at once. This is mostly convenient for flexible layouts or re-usage. For you however, it is more about code clearity (you can have 1 Activity that is your main, instead of an extra one that just switches between 2 others) and avoiding an extra transition animation. Like i said, for your case its a small difference.

Comment: And just to add to that, you really should take time to dive into Fragments. They're are the core of building flexible, responsive Android apps at the moment.

Comment: i need to spend some time on fragments, I know it will be helpful in some other cases for sure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by using fragments, than after the onCreate() you only have to commit the needed page, but there is nothing wrong with your solution neither. Just create a StartupActivity, check for the info you need (show some splash screen or something, as I assume this check runs on a background thread) and based on the results start the corresponding activity.

Comment: what's better way to do this using fragments or do it in background check in first activity? why?

Comment: Well, I prefer to use fragments, as that way you won't have to deal with some context reated issues (e.g. there is getActivity()), you won't miss to put them into the manifest file, it's a relatively new tech, so it's up to date and it's a good way to separate your code into modules, but there is nothing wrong with the other solution neither.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a definite answer to your question so i will just state what i prefer to do in your case. I would avoid having an extra activity and would have gone with your first suggestion. In the login activity, just for being visually correct i would have created an `AsyncTask` which would check if the user is logged in. This `AsyncTask` should have a non cancel-able `ProgressDialog` with a message such as

> Checking login infomation...

This `AsyncTask` should be called last in your `onCreate` method presumably.

Something like this:

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

        //It may be a good idead to make the Views handling the login process invisible

        //Do whatever initialization work for the on create method here.
        .
        .
        .

        new CheckLoginAsyncTask().execute(); //This ideally should be called last. But it depends on the situation.
    }

    .
    .
    .



    private class GetVisitReasonsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>  {

         private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() { //Do the progress dialog initialization here...
         progressDialog = ProgressDialog
                .show(myActivityContext,
                        getString(R.string.ProgressDialogTitle),
                        getString(R.string.ProgressDialogMessage));
        }

            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return checkLogin(); //Check login is boolean method returning true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isLoggedIn) {
                 dialog.dismiss(); //dismiss the dialog

                 if(isLoggedIn) {
                     //User is logged in, finish this activity and go to main menu
                 } else {
                     //User is not logged in, stay in this actity and make visible the the Views handling the login process if you had previously make them invisible. 
                 }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: other solution i got is to use fragments. do you think it's better to do it this way instead of using fragment? why?

Comment: @BSThakar I do not think there is a best approach in your case. Even if you use fragments you have to do the background check. Fragments in general give you more flexibility in your UI but in your case i do not think that additional flexibility will be in use.

Comment: "This AsyncTask should have a non cancel-able ProgressDialog with a message such as"  - please do not.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn What you had showed me is a design suggestion (thank you btw i was not aware of it). I agree with it, however i do not agree with the absolute rejection of ProgressDialog. If you handle correctly the lifecycle of the ProgressDialog i do not see why you should avoid it. In certain occasions it is important the user not to be able to interrupt the process (depending on the occasion, the login process can be considered as such).

Comment: @Angelo Yeah, its just a design suggestion and everyone is free to choose his own way of doing things. However, I personally do no not take this suggestion lightly, as it comes from one of the core Android team developer. Also Reto Meier, another key asset of the Android team, has made the same point multiple times. If it can somehow be avoided, it should be.